# Rounded corners for <input type='text' /> using border-radius.htc for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners, css

I want to create an input fields with rounded corners.

HTML:

```
<div id="RightColumn">
<input type="text" class="inputForm" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inputForm
{
    -moz-border-radius:10px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
    border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
    behavior:url("border-radius.htc");
}

#RightColumn
{
    background-color:White;
}
```

But IE doesn't show any borders for input fields - neighter rounded nor simple borders.
When I remove CSS-style for #RightColumn, IE shows an input fields with rounded corners.
But I need background for #RightColumn.

How can I create it?

Comment: [W3C doc says regarding "border-radius" property:](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) "supported in IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera". What version of IE do you require this to work on??

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css

Comment: related too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654745/rounded-corners-of-input-elements-in-ie

Comment: "What version of IE do you require this to work on??"
Adrien Be, this question was set Jul 18 '10, but IE9 was released on March 14, 2011. I could not predict the future, sorry)

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't realized IE9 was released so late.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Oh lord, don't do it this way. HTC files are never a good idea for performance and clarity reasons, and you're using too many vendor-specific parameters for something that can easily be done cross-browser all the way back to IE6.

Apply a background image to your input field with the rounded corners and make the field's background colour transparent with border:none applied instead.

Comment: i like the "Oh lord" ahahah :)

Comment: IE8 is still used very widely unfortunately. here seems to be an answer https://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/

Comment: here is the start of a real answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654745/rounded-corners-of-input-elements-in-ie

Comment: Of course IE8 is still widely used. I noted in my answer that using background images instead of HTC files would work cross-browser back to IE6, which was still widely used in 2010 when this answer was originally posted, that's two versions below the one you're telling me is still in use.

Comment: While this might have been a good answer in 2010, its not a good answer in 2016 as *all* major browsers support border radius now.

Comment: Yeah, i'm still getting upvotes on this 6 years later, and it's way out of date. That said, htc files still aren't the right answer :-)

Comment: hi, what is the 2016 vanilla js and css, Mac, Linux, Android, windows devices ... Safari, Firefox and chrome compatible answer ?

Comment: Just like @Shayne says above - you can now use border-radius in all major browsers to achieve this. According to caniuse the only browser that doesn't support it is Opera Mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: Arguably the "right" answer back then and now is "Dont use IE"  :P

Answer (score 15):

```
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #b3b3b3;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #b3b3b3;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #b3b3b3;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
```

...Who cares IE6 we are in 2011 upgrade and wake up please!

Comment: what kind of answer is that? the question even has better code than yours: it has mozilla, webkit, & khtml border radius.

Answer (score 7):

if you are  using for certain text field then use the class

```
<style>
  .inputForm{
      border-radius:5px;
      -moz-border-radius:5px;
      -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   }
</style>
```

and in html code use

```
 <input type="text" class="inputForm">
```

or if u want to do this for all the input type text field means use

```
<style>
    input[type="text"]{
      border-radius:5px;
      -moz-border-radius:5px;
      -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    }
 </style>
```

and in html code

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Answer (score 3):

That won't work in IE<9 though, however, you can make IEs support that using:

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8
>   capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Comment: Does CSS3Pie support input elements as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem with behavior:url("PIE.htc");

Answer (score 2):

[W3C doc says regarding "border-radius" property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp): "supported in IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera".

Hence I assume you're testing on IE8 or below.

For "regular elements" there is a solution compatible with IE8 & other old/poor browsers. See below.

HTML:

```
<div class="myWickedClass">
  <span class="myCoolItem">Some text</span> <span class="myCoolItem">Some text</span> <span class="myCoolItem"> Some text</span> <span class="myCoolItem">Some text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myWickedClass{
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  background: #F7D358 url(../img/roundedCorner_right.png) top right no-repeat scroll;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 11px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #A4A4A4;
}
.myWickedClass > .myCoolItem:first-child {
  padding-left: 6px;
  background: #F7D358 url(../img/roundedCorner_left.png) 0px 0px no-repeat scroll;
}
.myWickedClass > .myCoolItem {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

You need to create both **roundedCorner_right.png** & **roundedCorner_left.png**. These are work around for IE8 (& below) to fake the rounded corner feature.

So in this example above we apply the left rounded corner to the first span element in the containing div, & we apply the right rounded corner to the containing div. These images overlap the browser-provided "squary corners" & give the illusion of being part of a rounded element.

The idea for inputs would be to do the same logic. However, input is an empty element, " element is empty, it contains attributes only", in other word, **you cannot wrap a span into an input** such as `<input><span class="myCoolItem"></span></input>` to then use background images like in the previous example.

Hence the solution seems to be to do the opposite: wrap the input into another element. see this answer [rounded corners of input elements in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654745/rounded-corners-of-input-elements-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Writing from phone, but curvycorners is really good, since it adds it's own borders only if browser doesn't support it by default. In other words, browsers which already support some CSS3 will use their own system to provide corners.
https://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/

Comment: That's weird, I've used it before on inputs.

Comment: Try adding `display: block;` to that input class.