# Input field text with rounded corners and padding in IE 9/10

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, input-field

I have an input text field with rounded corners and some padding (basic bootstrap styling). 
The situation is that the user writes text that is longer than the width of the text field, and then navigates away from the field. In IE, the last part of the text that can fit the input field is displayed. The situation is when I have padding and border-radius, some letters of the last word is hidden (depending on how much padding there is).

For the user, this looks like he forgot to write one (or more) characters. Is there a way

To test this, use IE and add a letter to the end of the text of the third input field in the following fiddle, and then notice that the character you added is not display: 
http://jsfiddle.net/56SMV/3/

```
<input type="text" value="Some text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" style="padding:20px; border-radius: 10px;  border-style: solid; border-color: #CCCCCC;" />
```

Screenshot here (the third input field):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2s1W.png

Is there any easier way to fix this than creating rounded corners with a background image?
[Rounded corners for <input type='text' /> using border-radius.htc for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274950/rounded-corners-for-input-type-text-using-border-radius-htc-for-ie)

Comment: Re your last point -- That question you linked to is only relevant for older IE versions (IE<=8). You should not need a htc hack, or any of the other answers to that linked question in IE9/10.

Comment: Make sure the `doctype` is set to `html` (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). IE may be rendering in quirks/compatibility mode, which would cause border radius to not work. According to http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius it should work in ie 9 and 10.

Comment: If you want to allow the user to type more than what fits in the visible part of the input, I would set the right padding to 0. That also would have the advantage of looking more similar across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Jack: I confirmed that IE is not running in quirks mode. @Mr Lister: I would prefer a solution where I can use padding in the input field, as I'm using bootstrap css for the whole site and the input fields look a lot better with some padding.