# how to generate rounded corner input field along with input-group-addon in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

How can I create rounded corner input field along with input-group-addon in bootstrap .

Exaple:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBy4g.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded corners for <input type='text' /> using border-radius.htc for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274950/rounded-corners-for-input-type-text-using-border-radius-htc-for-ie)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you,

Add this css into your file

```
      .round{
      border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
      border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;

      -moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
      border-top-right-radius:15px;
      border-top-left-radius:15px;
       }
```

HTML code

```
  <div class = "input-group">
     <input type = "text" class = "form-control round">
     <span class = "input-group-addon round">icon</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `border-radius: 20px` to your element in CSS